# Django, ajax upload file with extra data

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a little question, I want to upload a file with some extra data.

So what I'm doing now is:

#### JS file:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.upload-file', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form_data = new FormData($(this)); //I dont know why, but it used to return None
        //so I append file and some extra data
        form_data.append( 'file', ($(this).find('[type=file]')[0].files[0]) );
        form_data.append( 'expire', ($(this).find('.document-id').val()) );
        form_data.append( 'document', ($(this).find('[type=datetime-local]').val()) );

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'some_url',
        data : form_data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);      
    });

});
```

#### Views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        file = request.FILES

        print('File ->', file) #this one prints File
        print('Data ->', data) #this one prints None

        return HttpResponse()
```

#### Printed data:

```
 File -> <MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: MyFile.docx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)>]}>
 Data -> None
```

So, I need to send file to external Server, which requires some extra information, but I have no idea how to combine this data.

Comment: Did you not get an error because of csrf token ?

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard to guess that you need to set the content type of your request. In your AJAX call, you are passing `contentType: false`. Maybe try changing that to `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`?